# Every orthogonal matrix represents a rotation around an axis

Tags: lie-groups, euclidean-geometry

Is it true that every element of the group $O(n)$ represents a rotation around some axis? I'd like this to be true in order to decompose any matrix $R \in O(n)$ as a block matrix in $O(n-1)$ and a 1 that represents a rotation around this axis.

Comment: In $n$ dimensions we tend to rotate around $(n-2)$-dimensional hyperplanes instead of axes. However, already for $n=4$ this fails to hold for all elemens of $O(n)$

Answer (score 1):

This is only true for $n\le 3$. For $n\ge 4$ there are orthogonal matrices having no real eigenvalues.  Such a matrix isn't "rotating" around any fixed vector. For example consider for $n=4$ matrices
\begin{pmatrix} R(\theta) & 0 \\ 0 & R(\psi)\end{pmatrix} where $R(\theta)$ and $R(\psi)$ are rotation matrices, with appropriate choices of $\phi$ and $\psi$. with no real eigenvalues.

Comment: Is there another reason, then, to exists some decomposition of O(n), as we have in SO(n) for odd n, differently from demanding this submatrix to be a rotation around some axis? I want to show that O(n-1) is always a subgroup of O(n), that's when I wanted to check this argument.